# jquery tabs - im having trouble making my <li> clickable

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tabs

This is my tabbed interface, I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3EyCT/).

```
<div class="tabs">
  <!-- tabs -->
  <ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li><a href="#corporations">Corporations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#non-profit">non-profit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#growing-businesses">growing-businesses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#arrange">Arrange a meetup</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- tab containers -->
  <div id="corporations">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="non-profit">
    <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="growing-businesses">
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
  </div>
  <div id="arrange">
    <p>Sed do ad minim ipsum dolor sit</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my jquery which is simple enough.

```
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');

    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

        $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

My problem is I know how to easily manipulate an `<a>` in order to change the contents on hover or click, which I have already done in the jsfiddle. But I want to hover or click the `<li>` and change the information in the container to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is select the `<li>` elements and bind a `click` event handler, just the same as for a link:

```
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');

    //here I am targeting the `<li>` elements instead of the `<a>` elements
    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation li').click(function () {

        //to get the "hash" you need to select the child `<a>` element of this `<li>` element
        var the_hash = $(this).children().attr('href');
        tabContainers.hide().filter(the_hash).show();

        //and here the `selected` class is being added and removed from the `<li>` elements rather than the `<a>` elements
        $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3EyCT/5/